# C: Is it possible to create an array of Clang Blocks?

Tags: c, clang

You probably know a feature of the Clang compiler called `Blocks`.
Is there a way to create an array of Blocks?
My attempt looks like this but it doesn't compile:

```
const void (^write_pckt_props)(const int, struct pckt_idntfy*)[] = {
    ^(const int prop_idx, struct pckt_idntfy *pckt) {
        /* empty */
    },
    ^(const int prop_idx, struct pckt_idntfy *pckt) {
        /* empty */
    }
};
```

And someone would be able to call it via `write_pckt_props[i]()`.

Any ideas if that's possible at all?

Comment: "Doesn't compile" means it produced an error, which is something you should include, verbatim, in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. This is how it's done:

```
const void (^write_pckt_props[])(const int, struct pckt_idntfy*) = {
    ^(const int prop_idx, struct pckt_idntfy *pckt) {
        /* empty */
    },
    ^(const int prop_idx, struct pckt_idntfy *pckt) {
        /* empty */
    }
};

write_pckt_props[0](0, NULL);
```